# Parsing jsoup error. Root element null

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I would parsing with jsoup this page: http://www.verlata.it/eventi
and in this my doInBackground() method:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                errore = false;
                final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.verlata.it/eventi").timeout(30000).get();

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (doc != null) {
                                rootElement = doc.body().getElementById("div#container");
                            } else {
                                errore = true;
                                Log.d("errore", "errore parsing 1");
                                notFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                notFound.setText("Ops, something went wrong. Maybe the blog is offline or please check your connection.");

                            } 
                            if (rootElement != null) {
                                Elements elements = rootElement.getElementsByTag("div#body_content");
                                for(Element element : elements){
                                    if (!errore) {
                                    String descrizione = element.select("div").text();
                                    String titolo = element.select("h2").text();
                                    //String urldesc = element.select("h2 a").first().attr("abs:href");


                                    titoli.add(titolo);
                                    descrizioni.add(descrizione);
                                    //url.add(urldesc);
                                    } else {
                                        errore = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                errore = true;
                                Log.d("errore", "errore parsing 2");
                                notFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                notFound.setText("Ops, something went wrong. Maybe the blog is offline or please check your connection.");

                            }
                        }
                    });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                /*Toast.makeText(FragmentThree.this, "Errore parsing",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                Log.d("errore", "errore parsing");
                notFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notFound.setText("Ops, something went wrong. Maybe the blog is offline or please check your connection.");
            }


        return null;
    }
```

the logcat reports me this: `Log.d("errore", "errore parsing 2");` so it means that rootElement is null.. how is possible? What i need is the title of the post and its description.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
doc.body().getElementById("div#container");
```

That method expects just the ID of the element, not the entire search query.

```
doc.body().getElementById("container");
```

If you want to use the full search query, use this:

```
doc.select("div#container");
```

The same applies to this line:

```
Elements elements = rootElement.getElementsByTag("div#body_content");
```

It should be

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div#body_content");
```

---

Your code would look like this:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.verlata.it/eventi").timeout(30000).get();
Element container = doc.body().getElementById("container");
Element bodyContent = doc.body().getElementById("body_content");
System.out.println(container);
System.out.println(bodyContent);
```

Comment: mmh i tried but i get the same error...i don't know why.. maybe wrong id?

Comment: @End.Game Did you try the one with `doc.select`?

Comment: well i think that there is a problem with this website.. the "description" is a div..without any id..how can i parse it?

Comment: @End.Game What do you mean by "description"?

Comment: look at the website.. the part for example: "Dal 31 Marzo 2015 la fatturazione verso tutte le..." etc etc.

Comment: mmh... and the h2? because what i want is create a listview with title (the h2 element) and the description (the div of body content).. both.. understand?

Comment: @End.Game You should read up the jsoup documentation. `bodyContent.getElementsByTag("h2")` will give you all the elements with the `h2` tag inside the `div` which has id `body_content`.

Comment: i tried in this way for the description: String descrizione = element.select("div#body_content div").text(); but not works. the title works now

Comment: ok wait..something happened! I can display only one result and this is a problem.. i have only one item in listview in wich there is as title all h2 elements and as description all div in the page..i need divide them for each item of the list

Comment: @End.Game [Here you can find the Javadoc for Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html), which is the type returned by the `getElementsByTagName` method. Please take a look at it, it contains all the informations you need to go on with your work.